# Encrypting database tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows application using a database in SQL Server 2008.

I do not want users to see the database tables.

How can I **encrypt** tables in my database?

Comment: If you are a administrator, instead you can restrict them by giving writeonly permissions right?

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala : I am not Administrator. I am a developer of project. I've delivered the project to Administrator, But i can not Administrator and users able to see database tabels and data tabels.

Comment: Why don't you want them to see the tables - and why won't the administrator lock down their access?

Comment: Users have not access to the database. 
This database is host in elsewhere. For more security, I want encrypt tables of my database that No one can see them

Answer (score 8):

You have different options here.

- You can use symmetric encryption for your data:

  CREATE TABLE sales (
     ...
  )

Create symmetric key:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE cert_sales WITH SUBJECT = N'Sales certificate',
START_DATE = N'2009-01-01', EXPIRY_DATE = N'2018-12-31';

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY symkey_sales WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE cert_sales
```

Encrypt data:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE sales;
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY symkey_sales DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE cert_sales;
INSERT INTO sales() SELECT a, ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_Guid(N'symkey_sales'), B) FROM T2;
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY symkey_sales;
```

Decrypt data:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY symkey_sales DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE cert_sales;
SELECT a, CAST(DecryptByKey(B) as nvarchar(100)) FROM sales;
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY symkey_sales;
```

- You can use asymmetric encryption for your data
- You can use **Transparrent Data Encryption** for encrypt all database files:

Create master key:

```
USE master
go
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'My$Strong$Password$123'
```

Create certificate:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE DEK_EncCert WITH SUBJECT = 'DEK Encryption Certificate'
```

Create DEK:

```
USE MySecretDB
go
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE DEK_EncCert
```

Turn on encryption:

```
ALTER DATABASE MySecretDB SET ENCRYPTION ON
```

- You can use BitLocker - complete volume encryption

Answer (score 3):

Encryption wont help - SQL Server level encryption encrypts the files. The data is visible once you log in.

The only proper solution is called "programming". Basically go client/server and don't have users connect to the database.

Alternatively you could use permissions on the tables + an application password to elevate the rights for the application (not the user), but that is unsafe too (because you have to put the password somewhere).

Answer (score -1):

The users won't see the content of the tables if you don't grant them SELECT permission. This means that they should NOT connect as members of the dbo group. Instead create one or more groups for the various security groups of users and assign permissions to the database objects you do want them to access to those groups.

Note that if you have a group of objects that will be collectively permissioned to one or more user groups, you can create these groups in a separate **schema** and then grant the user group permission to access the entire schema. This makes permissioning a one-time affair as you add database objects to the schema.

Comment: This does not answer the op. Security and encryption are two separate but often overlapping concerns.