# How can I disable a table in a SQL Server database from SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

I inherited a SQL Server database used with a C# client application. I know enough to be dangerous but I'm not a programmer. I know the previous programmer liked to play around in the live database and as a result I have a number of what I think are orphaned tables.

The application itself isn't super high-usage and can withstand the exceptions of tables not being there for a small time frame. I'd like to start turning off or disabling these tables to see they're being used anymore through trial and error.

Is there a way to turn them off without completely removing the data so that I can re-enable them quickly if needed? Or is there a more transparent way to discover whether those tables are needed?

Comment: Well, that's a pretty brute force method of doing it, can't you just search the sourcecode for the table name instead? How do you know you're testing every single function? If you *really* want to do this, just rename the table.

Comment: You can just rename the table. Maybe append ".testing" or something to the name.

Comment: See [How can I tell if a database table is being accessed anymore? Want something like a “SELECT trigger”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155594/how-can-i-tell-if-a-database-table-is-being-accessed-anymore-want-something-lik)

Comment: Are there clustered indexes on the tables? If yes, you can disable them. This effectively makes the table inaccessible. Then you can rebuild the clustered index, if needed.

Comment: We have also used a Database Audit to see if stuff is being used.

Comment: @DavidG - That's the point of the question.  I'm hoping to find a better way but my limited experience with SSMS doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way.  The tables can be accessed through both stored procedures and direct SQL calls from your client application.  A comprehensive approach would mean that you'd have to have some way of making each table unavailable (renaming has been suggested in comments) and then perform a full regression test on your client application; you might have to do this with *each* table in the database.  The client application might access the tables conditionally, subject to external things like the logged-in user (and related privileges), the date, configuration, and so forth.

The [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) is a good tool to use, but it's not going to solve your problem all by itself because you still have to analyze what it captures.

Comment: The application does indeed use both stored procedures and SQL calls from the client.  A goal of mine is to migrate all SQL queries to stored procedures for consistency and my personal sanity.  But first I want to clean up the existing clutter. I'm positive renaming tables isn't the best approach but being small scale and limited usage, it's probably something I can live with.  I have a gut feeling 3 tables are just dead but I'm not comfortable just flat out removing the tables and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new db schema and transfer the tables to that schema

ALTER SCHEMA new schema TRANSFER dbo.your table

Then transfer them back again after testing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions so that no one except you and the dbos have select permission on the table. You cannot prevent a dbo or sa from having all permissions on a table.

You can also encrypt the table see- [Encrypting database tables in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427001/encrypting-database-tables-in-sql-server-2008) in which case it is really locked down.

You can also used SQL Server Audit to see if anyone reads the data. Audit is a very low impact product (comes with SQL Server 2008) and is very easy to set up and can audit selects unlike a trigger.